# OAuth 2 Decorator + Flask = AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: check_oauth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, flask, google-api

I've been trying to get Google API decorator for OAuth to work with Flask on Google Appengine, but so far unsuccessfully. This is something that's done pretty easy with the default: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication structure.

```
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json'), 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')

@app.route('/my-page')
@decorator.oauth_required
def dashboard():
    pass
```

This returns the following error "AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: check_oauth"

However it works just fine in the basic App:

```
class MyPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        pass

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/my-page', MyPage),
    (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())
], debug=True)
```

Thank you